# Closed-form expression of generating function of this series

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, closed-form

I want to find closed-form expression of generating function of $<1,2,...,k,...>$. How can i figure that out?

Comment: Have you even tried to write the sum ? What did you get?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i find closed-form expression of generating function of this series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2298123/how-can-i-find-closed-form-expression-of-generating-function-of-this-series)

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that 
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k.$$
That is $f$ is the generating function  of the constant sequence $1,1,1,1,\dots$.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following. First write down your generating function in its power series form. Then look for the closed form function that yields that power series as Maclaurin series expansion. For your particular problem I think the answer is $g(x) = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$.