# How to find closed-form expression of this series?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, closed-form

> Find closed-form expression of generating function of this series:
>
> $<0,1,4,k^2,...>$

How can i find the expression?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i find closed-form expression of generating function of this series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2298123/how-can-i-find-closed-form-expression-of-generating-function-of-this-series)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $G(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2x^n$.

To find this, start with the geometric series:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

Differentiate both sides and multiply by $x$:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$

And one more time:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2x^n = \frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}$$

So $\displaystyle G(x) = \frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
n^2=\binom{n+1}{2}+\binom{n}{2}\tag{1}.
$$
Also 
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^k}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{k+n-1}{k-1}x^n\tag{2}.
$$
for $k\geq 1$ (by repeatedly differentiating the geometric series or by the extended binomial theorem). In particular
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+2}{2}x^n\tag{3}.
$$ 
Mutiply by $x^n$ and sum on $n$ in (1) to get that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2x^n
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+1}{2}x^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n}{2}x^n
=\frac{x}{(1-x)^3}+\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^3}
=\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}.\tag{4}
$$
by (3).